# How to write equivalent JPQL query for LEFT OUTER JOIN written in native sql?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpql

This is the native query -

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT CA FROM CLASS_ATTRIBUTE,WORD_PROCESSING WHERE ( word_processing.uoid  = class_attribute.c_user_explanation(+)) ORDER BY CLASS_ATTRIBUTE.DESCRIPTION ASC
```

I tried the following JPQL query, but it didn't work -

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT CA FROM ClassAttribute CA LEFT JOIN CA.WordProcessing AS WP ON ( WP.id  = CA.userExplanationUoid) ORDER BY CA.description ASC")
```

Also tried the following JPQL  -

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT CA FROM ClassAttribute CA LEFT OUTER JOIN CA.WordProcessing AS WP WHERE ( WP.id  = CA.userExplanationUoid) ORDER BY CA.description ASC")
```

The compilation goes into an infinite loop if I try these. Something from the Spring  framework is causing it to refresh again and again. There seems to be some issue with the syntax of the converted JPQL query.

[image: The screenshot of the error -]

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ representation of your problem.  No one should have to read through such a verbose query.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have done that .

Comment: `TO_CHAR` is not a JPQL keyword. If you want people might help you, you may post the entities and their mappings as well. Otherwise, difficult to formulate the queries correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that here the issue was with the pom.xml where **hibernate.entitymanager.version** was 5.0.12.Final. Changing it to 5.1.10.Final did the trick for me.

Since hibernate.entitymanager is now deprecated by Maven (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager), it actually downloaded the jar hibernate-core:5.1.10.Final because of which JOIN related queries are working fine now.